# convert numeric tick to date in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

First, I don't have producible data, so please don't bother to comment about this.

I was tring to generate a graph using ggplot2().

Then, x-axis is in numberic version. Data frame has also x=1~10, y=blah blah.

Eveything was fine, till now, I need to convert x-axis ticks to DATE.

I have created a "break" as a serie of dates that CORRESPONDING to numeric 1~10, and used scale_x_date.

As I can image, R returns errors, saying "INVALID INPUT: date_trans works with objects of class Date only".

Is this because I draw the lines and graphs in numeric, but add a scale of date as x-axis ticks?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your x-axis to an R recognized format, see:

```
as.Date()
as.POSIXct()
```